# Take $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and for each $r\in \mathbb{R}$ collect $f(r)$ in $\mathcal{A}_f$: what is $\mathcal{A}_f$?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Consider $f$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Suppose that for each $r\in \mathbb{R}$ I collect $f(r)$ in $\mathcal{A}_f$ (if for any $r\in \mathbb{R}, r'\in \mathbb{R}$ we have $f(r)=f(r')$, I put **both** $f(r), f(r')$ in $\mathcal{A}_f$).

Which mathematical object is $\mathcal{A}_f$? Uncountable infinite sequence (does it make any sense)? An interval of $\mathbb{R}$ (but then there are some points which could have more weight because they appear more than once)?

---

**EDIT:** I am updating my question thanks to the illuminating comments below which suggest that $\mathcal{A}_f$ is an uncountably infinite (multi)set.

I want to go deeper and ask

- Is there any specific name relating $\mathcal{A}_f$ to $f$ (e.g., the multiset *generated by* the function $f$)
- Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the collection of all functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the collection of $\mathcal{A}_f$ $\forall f \in \mathcal{F}$, where $\mathcal{A}_f$ is defined above. Does the object $\mathcal{A}$ make sense?
- Suppose I write the object $\mathcal{A}\times \{0,1\}$ where $\times$ denotes the Cartesian product. Is this Cartesian product well defined in math? Intuitively I just want to combine $\{0,1\}$ with any multiset in $\mathcal{A}$. Also, can I (sloppily) call an element of $\mathcal{A}\times \{0,1\}$ "a point", or is there any other specific name I should use?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset

Comment: @STF multiset can be uncountable. It is basically a set where multiplicity is allowed.